# How to use mupdf to generate 8-bit indexed png for pdf files

Tags: image, pdf, png, mupdf

BACKGROUND: I have been playing with a variety of tools to generate images from pdfs including graphicsmagick, ghostscript and now mupdf (I haven't tried poppler but I use that for other things at the moment). mupdf seems to generate high quality images and the performance in my quick tests appears better than graphicsmagick. Calling ghostscript directly got eliminated because the quality wasn't hitting the mark on my tests (without giving a crazy r value and blowing up the size) and when I added the -dINTERPOLATE flag to improve quality, it started crashing on some of my test cases (removing the flag fixed it). At the moment, mupdf seems to be the best for my targeted scenario

QUESTION: mupdf seems to generate 24-bit png files but for the files I am working with, I would like to use 8-bit indexed and save on file size. I have tried using some tools like pngquant to convert to 8-bit and, for my documents, the image quality is not noticeably different and the file size is much smaller. Seems like mupdf would be able to output 8-bit and save me the perf hit of converting after generating. Is there a flag? I am using mudraw at the moment, but if I have to, I could edit the utility source and build for my purposes (since I can't find a flag on that tools commandline).

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 0):

8-bit quantized colors look dreadful! If you want 8-bit to save on space and retain high quality, render to grayscale instead of full color with `mudraw -g`.